# Pandas assign a pd series with longer len than df, to a col in that df

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
new_series = pd.Series([7, 8,9,10], name='C')
df['B'] = new_series
```

in this code the column 'B' does not get replaced with new series. so I want the df to be

```
df["B"]=[1, 2, 3,nan]
df["B"]=[7, 8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make indices between `df` and `new_series` agreed, then - assign the needed column:

```
df.reindex(new_series.index).assign(B=new_series)
```

---

```
     A   B
0  1.0   7
1  2.0   8
2  3.0   9
3  NaN  10
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:-1], new_series.rename('B')], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     A   B
0  1.0   7
1  2.0   8
2  3.0   9
3  NaN  10
```